# Python3 shared extension doesn't link against library dependency

Tags: python, setup.py, distutils

I'm creating a shared Python extension for my library and I'm using `distutils` to build it.

These are the relevant sections of my `setup.py`:

```py
import distuitls.core as dc
from os.path import join as path_join

module = dc.Extension(module_name, 
                      sources = [path_join(meson_src_root, "py3_bindings", "module.c")], 
                      include_dirs = [path_join(meson_src_root, "include")],
                      libraries = ["bbmputil"],
                      runtime_library_dirs = [meson_build_root])

dc.setup(name = module_name,
         version = module_version,
         description = "Python3 bindings for the bbmp_utils library",
         ext_modules = [module])
```

---

Running `$ setup.py build` results in the shared extension module being built successfully, but it isn't getting linked against the `"bbmputil"` library.

```sh
$ ldd build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/bbmp_utils.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc85ce1000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f49f0d70000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f49f0f74000)
```

`libbbmputil.so` is nowhere to be found, despite being specified in the `libraries` kwarg of `Extension()`.

It does exist in the location specified in the `runtime_library_dirs` kwarg.

---

This leads to the python interpreter raising an `ImportError` exception when a symbol from the non-linked library is referenced in the extension:

```sh
$ env PYTHONPATH="sharedextension_build_path" python3
```

```
>>> import bbmp_utils
ImportError: /home/bogdan/dev/bbmp_utils/build_dbg/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/bbmp_utils.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: bbmp_vertflip
```

where `bbmp_vertflip` is a symbol defined in the library that doesn't seem to be linked for some reason.

---

The two C compiler invocations look as follows:

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fPIC -I/home/bogdan/dev/bbmp_utils/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c /home/bogdan/dev/bbmp_utils/py3_bindings/module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/home/bogdan/dev/bbmp_utils/py3_bindings/module.o
```

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/home/bogdan/dev/bbmp_utils/py3_bindings/module.o -L/usr/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/home/bogdan/dev/bbmp_utils/build_dbg -lbbmputil -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/bbmp_utils.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

In the 2nd invocation both `-lbbmputil` as well as `-R` are passed properly when building the shared extension so I'm out of ideas.

---

### Minimal example producing the same behavior

Attempting to build a module that utilizes functions and other symbols from the math shared library:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import distutils.core as dc

module = dc.Extension('example',
                      sources = ['example.c'],
                      libraries = ['m'])
dc.setup(name = 'example',
         version = '0.1',
         ext_modules = [module])
```

```sh
$ ./setup.py build
```

```sh
$ ldd .../.../example.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd0b9e5000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fab528e8000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fab52aec000)
```

---

Again, `libm.so` dependency is nowhere to be found.

---

Environment:

- python3 3.8.1
- linux 5.4.6
- gcc 9.2.0
- ld 2.33.1
- ldd 2.3.0

Comment: Does the build log show the .so being linked against bbmputil?

Comment: It shows 2 compiler invocations both of which I've listed in the question. The latter (which links the .o into an .so) passes `-lbbmp` to gcc and `-R...` to the linker properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE : The problem in this case is the *linker optimization option*
>   `--as-needed` **that is enabled by default**, see
>   [Missing a library in ldd after using gcc -l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329967/missing-a-library-in-ldd-after-using-gcc-l)
>
> Adding `--no-as-needed` fixes this error

For debugging linker errors you can use `LD_DEBUG=files,libs /usr/local/ABC/bin/ABC` where `ABC` is the executable that throws linker errors at runtime, cf http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html and [libm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904192/libm-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) On linux you locate a `.so` with i.e. `locate libm` (i think you know this)

As the linking is dynamically it is an option to specify the path where your `.so` files can be found using the  `library_dirs` option of `disutils.core` that is the `-L` or equivalently `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gcc linker option and for reasons of debugging and testing i would use the **absolute path** (https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html)

In your python minimal example the code is then :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import distutils.core as dc

module = dc.Extension('example',
                      sources = ['example.c'],
                      library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so'],
                      libraries = ['m'])
dc.setup(name = 'example',
         version = '0.1',
         ext_modules = [module])
```

You use the `-R` linker flag to specify the `rpath` in your gcc invokation, cf [Shared library dependencies with distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795793/shared-library-dependencies-with-distutils) and  [What does the gcc -R parameter do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860024/what-does-the-gcc-r-parameter-do) . In https://www.mpcdf.mpg.de/services/computing/software/libraries/static-and-dynamic-linking-on-linux-systems is a description of the linking process. It is said that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or equivalently the `-L` gcc linker option overrides the rpath and that it should be avoided, however you should give it a try anyway ...

Another possiblity for this behavior could be permission problems, i.e. when you execute `example` does it have the permission to access `libm` cf https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303292/permission-denied-on-some-shared-libraries

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. The problem is not that the dynamic linker cannot find the shared library at runtime, it's that `ldd` doesn't even list it as a dependency.

Comment: And thus the linker has no reason to even look for it at runtime.

Comment: This still can be a library path problem if `ldd` does not list the library, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171908/why-does-not-ldd-output-the-libraries-that-i-have-linked-when-generating-the-exe

Comment: When searching more there are other possibilities for this error like *default optimization flags* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329967/missing-a-library-in-ldd-after-using-gcc-l

Comment: As of now I have also tried using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as well passing an absolute path to the `library_dirs` kwarg but none have worked. Only preloading the library with the `LD_PRELOAD` env. var seems to work. I'll dive deeper into the answer @ralf htp linked.

Comment: That answer did the trick! Thank you. Modifying the commandline of the `gcc` invocation to include `--no-as-needed` as a linker option and relinking the shared object works. Though the question remains -- why does `distutils` pass this parameter to the compiler? How are you supposed to call external shared libraries from python modules?

Comment: Also -- could you update your answer to include this info so I can accept it?

Comment: I meant if you could update your answer to include at least a link to the answer you linked in the comment so I can accept your answer as correct.